# use adb to get the device name of android device

Tags: android, adb

I want to use the adb shell to find out the camera device name of my android device. Usually the name can be dev/video1, however, tablets of NEXUS and Smsung don't work that way.

Could anyone give me hint? About the procedure? How to use the adb shell?

THX!

Answer (score -1):

You can get shell access to your Android device via the following command.

```
adb shell
```

The application data is stored in the directory "/data/data/package_of_your_app".

```
// Assume the gesture file exists on your Android device
adb pull /sdcard/gestures ~/test
// Now copy it back
adb push ~/test/gesture /sdcard/gestures2
```

It will work for you.